# PHP loop doesn't increment counter

Tags: php

I am working on this code. Why am I not able to increment the `$start`? The output looks like `88888` only:

```
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i<= 5; $i++){
        $start = 8;
        echo $start;
        $start++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are assigning the `start` each time the loop executes. Each time the variable re-assign so that your output like this.

Comment: Define your `$start` variable before you run your `for(){....` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you always assign your value inside loop , take it out

```
<?php

    $start = 8;
    for($i = 1; $i<= 5; $i++){

        echo $start;
        $start++;
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment the value of start, you must declare it outside of the `for` loop.

```
<?php
    $start = 8;
    for($i = 1; $i<= 5; $i++){
        echo $start;
        $start++;
    }
?>
```